# Aggregates in c++

Tags: c++

In the following code why is that  the two statements are illegal

```
const int i[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

// float f[i[3]]; // Illegal

struct S { int i, j; };
const S s[] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
//double d[s[1].j]; // Illegal
int main() {}
```

Why are they illegal? The textual definition is as follows which i didn't understand.

> "In an array definition, the compiler must be able to generate code
>   that moves the stack pointer to accommodate the array. In both of the
>   illegal definitions above, the compiler complains because it cannot
>   find a constant expression in the array definition."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Array sized need to be constant expressions. Try this:

```
constexpr int i[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

float f[i[3]];
```

The `constexpr` keyword was introduced in C++11. Previous versions of C++ had no concept of such general constant expressions, and there was no equivalent concept.

Answer (score 2):

Because C++ doesn't support variable-length arrays, and `s[1].j` is not a compile-time constant.

What that quote refers to is the fact that `f` and `d` are in **automatic storage**. The run-time will clean their memory automatically when they go out of scope. As such, it must know the size beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

because d is static array, that means that it's size has to be know at compilation time.
Therefore you can't use non-const variables as size parameter.

But you can try

```
 const int i = 3;
 double d[i];
```

for example.

Comment: Don't confuse static with static storage.